# Is there a Javascript iCalendar lib?

Tags: javascript, icalendar, rfc2445

Is there an iCalendar library available for Javascript - parser or calendar object itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is another one from kewisch but still up-to-date

https://github.com/mozilla-comm/ical.js/

**EDIT**

There is also dhtmlx scheduler for showing a calendar in HTML.
http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/

Comment: You have to pay $419 in order to use the dhtmlx scheduler.

Answer (score 8):

There is also https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule which is more popular than the other choices here and still active at the time of writing.

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/kewisch/ical.js

By the guys behind Lightning for Thunderbird.

Answer (score 2):

All other answers are highly outdated.

- Use this [ics package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ics) for doing the ics generation
- There is some other options but this is easy and best
- You'll have to use some kind of online `RRULE` generator for the `recurrenceRule` property
- If you need ics readers/parsers then there is plenty of options for that.

Comment: which rrule generator are you using? I'm using https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule but I've been running into many issues

Comment: I had a very simple RRULE that I figured out myself from examples. Didn't need any generators.... Tell what's the issues, maybe we can help!

Comment: The OP asked for a parser, not an library to generate events.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few that were easy to find on google:

- [jQuery iCalendar plugin](http://keith-wood.name/icalendar.html)
- [javascript iCalendar plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsicalendar/)

Comment: [jQuery iCalendar](http://keith-wood.name/icalendar.html) will generate RFC2245 output from what I can gather, the javascript iCalendar plugin [jsicalendar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsicalendar/) wasn't finished.  Other misc. stuff includes some [google-caja rrule code](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/demos/calendar/rrule-cajita.js?r=4148), the [jquery-frontier-calendar](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-frontier-calendar/), [DHX Scheduler](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml).

Comment: The nearest I can find is [ijp iCalendar javascript parser](http://code.google.com/p/ijp/), which is not quite yet full RFC2245.

Comment: The [jQuery iCalendar plugin](http://keith-wood.name/icalendar.html) will actually parse an ical definition as well - slow off the mark but got it eventually :)