# Javascript Parser Google Calendar JSON Feed with Recurring events

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-calendar-api, rfc5545

I'm looking for a JavaScript / NodeJS library to parse a GoogleCalendar JSON Feed with **recurring events**. I need to know at least next event(s) from now.

Reccuring events do not have gd$when attributes but gd$recurrence with given content (RFC 5545):

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Paris:20121210T082000\r\nDTEND;TZID=Europe/Paris:20121210T085000\r\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR\r\nBEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\nTZID:Europe/Paris\r\nX-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Paris\r\nBEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\nTZOFFSETFROM:+0100\r\nTZOFFSETTO:+0200\r\nTZNAME:CEST\r\nDTSTART:19700329T020000\r\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU\r\nEND:DAYLIGHT\r\nBEGIN:STANDARD\r\nTZOFFSETFROM:+0200\r\nTZOFFSETTO:+0100\r\nTZNAME:CET\r\nDTSTART:19701025T030000\r\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU\r\nEND:STANDARD\r\nEND:VTIMEZONE\r\n
```

I found a [rules parser](http://github.com/skyporter/rrule_parser) on github but rules seems not working and parsing is a pain.

Comment: Google Calendar was written to RFC 2445, not RFC 5545.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10656965/1167333, looks like jQuery iCalendar plugin and ijp iCalendar javascript parser might be what you are looking for.also why not just querying the dares from google calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Google v2 API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/reference) I have to use custom parameters

- futureevents = true
- or singleevents = true
- with recurrence-expansion-end